# Can't access storage/public/folder in view after artisan storage:link laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am wanting to save two separate types of file uploads into the storage folder of laravel 5.8. The folders are storage/app/public/listing_documents and storage/app/public/listing_images. In my controller, I save them with the store function to ->store('public/listing_documents') etc.

I have run php artisan storage:link and in my public folder there is a symbolic link to "storage" with the subdirectories in it as well as the correct files.

How do I access this in my view? I have tried "src='{{asset('$listing->path')}}' which gets pulled from the database but the database is saving it as "public/listing_documemnts/file-name.png" so the src is not accurate because it's trying to access it in the wrong directory. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all your files will be under storage folder so therefor use `Storage facade` for this

try the below code

in your view use:

```
<img src="{{Storage::url($listing->path)}}"/>
```

Thanks.